# Capifony fails warming the cache

Tags: deployment, symfony, capistrano, capifony

Yesterday I made my 40th or 50th deployment of a Symfony2 system on a server. Everything fine so far. Today I get a nasty error. This is what happens:

```
 * executing `symfony:cache:warmup'
 * executing "cd /NFS2/oa_sf2/releases/20111214182506 && php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod"
    servers: ["151.1.111.19"]
    [151.1.111.19] executing command
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] Warming up the cache
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] [RuntimeException]
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] Error creating output file.
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] cache:warmup
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
 ** [out :: 151.1.111.19] 
    command finished
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

- No chance for further investigation into the cache folder because the whole code tree gets removed on rollback
- We know Capistrano features some way to disable the rollback but still we'd like to try understanding with no access on remote server - it must be something on *our* side, since yesterday it was all OK
- No change was made on the deployment user's read/write/execute rights

Please any suggestion on how to bring investigation forward?
Thanks a lot.

p.s. no similar question on Stacktrace addresses this peculiar issue.

Comment: Did you upgrade Symfony before this issue?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I have a similar problem but with assetic:dump (which runs fine locally and on a staging server).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not really a Capifony related question. In the end it only runs the Symfony command.

First try running `cache:warmup` task manually on the server.

It might be a **permissions** problem. Check what are the rights to the cache directory just before the warmup. You can do that by overwriting the task (just copy it and run `ls -l` on the cache directory before running an actual command).

You don't have to deploy every time to see what's wrong. Run cache:warmup command itself:

```
cap symfony:cache:warmup
```

I greped Symfony 2.0.7 sources and the [assetic's YUI compressor is the only place where such exception is thrown](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/Yui/BaseCompressorFilter.php#L98) (see link). This suggests it's a problem related to compressing your assets with assetic. Might be you added this feature recently and don't have java installed on the server.

Comment: It seems like we cannot run the YUI compressor. java is installed though. For the record I'll post here any insight might pop up.
Thanks a lot so far!

Answer (score 0):

Disk full? Maybe it gets full once it tries to warmup the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The cache warming is a symfony task AFAIU, it can be inspected through XDebug or its profiler.